# Invalid or nonexistent map configuration token

Tags: carto, image

I get the return message NON-VALID PICTURE URL in the POPUP in the CARTO map. when editing in CARTO I get the "Invalid or nonexistent map configuration token". Please forgive my ignorance as I am a newbie at Carto really.
I have followed all the docs and looked at questions but I still can't get the image in the header to display in a popup window.  The image is in the _URL column and is a valid .jpg that I can display by just pasting the URL for it into the address bar of the browser. Is there a size restriction or something like that? https://photos.app.goo.gl/3h6gHXIWQXOW8slo2 is the link to the photo held in Google photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the address of the final image, so in your case for that image you shared the address to have in your column is

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DxO8Z6pKfRGt0_3NPLUjGNhFcjDeuQCvROJV2QlnAersVXX3CDP9fWNHycLEUkTEqtZXX8V7Pi0j8XyHEYr__iPdz46SS_ruEwIU1L9aybFom5uYZkujqijKZksXMrTQPVSPDKaRAH5JQc1zIxvF-BfXSQOCo5txBbeU--slnTTipzxGPu-kVDJUkOEyiSQpScP_7b6aJPircO1A4DABSAT0Tn1U5_k_w7YAcJxz_pjWyoth0_Mf0Gly-izuLeb6bwxoAuY5ATCWe-64THf8L6V9CVrol3kMLOrcGo8MorqRjx_q0npQCZKNCVxBH8si0ROSfCiBxwzX6dzxJt_AOnlryqAket8d9xf1jp_d5G5ViX88TXypb9wCWEJB1S0RbG5Bqf6kyS6YVz1fEV9eAAOClaE2Qq3EcbG8NEqE4t0fHIqjE60vJHc7NAOdZ49o6tTI-yhyR2E0uh7RGyHSN1B8hjKBscto5zVAW3nKyMG-1bVRb_zK1LicZs8DggwTZj8Q5D5OtaLTPpzKhIxaxchXIvX_lDOdHZJlpq9qnGrs-VidBYKSCWhuvWWvagiJuLfcdNtw80wc12QWkO4GIEgnB4_esPCgDK040pQYAj1PJVIR0rZmkBW0pdhBE90gDe7RH1HmIVzT_wKwNOQzL78QayWTbeqr=w1446-h1084-no

Otherwise, the popup is trying to put a webpage in a `img` HTML tag, which of course is totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks I can see that now.  I have it working now great!

Comment: please mark then the answer as correct ^_^

Comment: The answer is correct but how do I mark it as such?

Comment: please mark the question as answered by clicking the green tick under this answer.

Comment: Sorry but in my browser there is no green tick. What can I do otherwise?

Comment: @Martin there's a detailed explanation on how StackExchange works [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Sorry I see it now, it's grey then turns green when you tick it. Thanks I didn't notice it greyed out there before.